Up-to-date examples of a docker-compose.yml?
I installed the docker engine by exactly following the instructions (using the repository) on the docker website (I'm on Debian 11) without skipping any steps.
I can definitely run the docker hello world.
I tried to install Docker desktop but it only supports Debian 12 and above so instead I went ahead and installed docker compose directly again following the instructions (again using the repository) without leaving anything out.
sudo apt install docker-compose-plugin didn't do anything so I took a guess and ran sudo apt install docker-compose. That seemed to work in that I can now run
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.25.0, build unknown

I attempted to build a container (with GPU) using docker-compose, using exactly the example on the docker website:
services:
  test:
    image: nvidia/cuda:12.3.1-base-ubuntu20.04
    command: nvidia-smi
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: 1
              capabilities: [gpu]

and I get the error:
$ docker-compose up --build -d
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.deploy.devices contains an invalid type, it should be a string

I've tried about 100 other things I won't bother listing here and they all fail with some random syntax error. I can't find any documentation or examples corresponding to the apparent version of docker I have, nor any way to update it.

You have an old version of docker compose. Remove it, and install through the command line using the instructions here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/standalone/#on-linux

I followed the instructions to set up Docker's apt repository. Does that not work? Do they not maintain it? Did I miss something? https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/#install-using-the-repository

Did I miss something? Could be.  I'm on Debian 11 could be just old. What is the output of whereis docker-compose? What si the pacakge version installed with apt?

services:
  test:
    image: nvidia/cuda:12.3.1-base-ubuntu20.04
    command: nvidia-smi
    devices:
      - /dev/nvidiactl:/dev/nvidiactl
      - /dev/nvidia-uvm:/dev/nvidia-uvm
      - /dev/nvidia-modeset:/dev/nvidia-modeset
      - /dev/nvidia0:/dev/nvidia0
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              capabilities: [gpu]

The command docker-compose up --build -d should work now

This seems the same as the original file, except for adding devices:.  Why does it help?

There are two versions of the Compose tool.  The docker-compose --version output shows you're using version 1.  This is the older version, and the format of the Compose file it supports is a little bit different from what Docker defines in the "Compose specification" documentation.
In particular, the meaning of a Compose file without version: is completely different.  The standalone Compose tool which you have interprets it as a "version 1" Compose file.  This format doesn't support several present-day Docker features like named volumes or networks.  It does not have a top-level services: container, which is the source of the specific error you're getting.  It also won't support the deploy: option.
With this version of Compose you need a version: declaration.  The Compose documentation still describes the version 2 and version 3 file formats as "legacy" formats, but you can use either of these formats unmodified with the modern plugin-based Compose.
The deploy: option in particular is part of the version 3 format.  However, if you're not using Docker Swarm, it will be ignored.  The most recent version of this is version 3.8 and you just need to add at the top of your file
version: '3.8'

I'd always put a version: line in my Compose file.  Use version: '4.x' if you're using one of the features in the Compose specification that's not part of the earlier file formats.
